# Changing duplicate a line hotkey in Jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter

To duplicate a line in Jupyter-notebook on a Mac, the hotkey is `cmd + shift + D`. The problem is I use Google Chrome, and this is the same hotkey to bookmark a webpage, which takes priority over the hotkey in Jupyter-notebook. Has anyone struggled with this before, and found a workaround? I would probably prefer to use this hotkey for duplicating a line because it's the same hotkey I use in IDEs and text editors.

Comment: You should be able to edit your hotkeys for jupyter notebook: "Head to the 'Help' menu and select the 'Edit keyboard Shortcuts' item". See also [this link](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extending/keymaps.html) for more information.

Comment: @Oxbowerce I tried this before, but in the list of editable hotkeys, I don't see "Duplicate a line" or similar.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the Chrome shortcut like this:

In System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts, click the [+] button, and select Google Chrome as the Application. Put `Bookmarks->Bookmark All Tabs...` in the Menu Title and a different Keyboard Shortcut.